# Scheme filter function

Tags: filter, scheme, filtering

So far i have made two functions to apply a filter to a list. I am trying to get the functions to return only the elements that the operation applies to for instance all odd numbers. I am only returning a boolean of whether each number is odd.

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
   (if (null? sequence)
       initial
       (op (car sequence)
           (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))

(define (my-filter predicate sequence)
    (accumulate (lambda (element rest)(cons (predicate element) rest)) '()      sequence))



(my-filter odd? (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the `predicate` in a conditional expression. If the predicate evaluates to `#t` then add the current element to the answer, otherwise skip it:

```
(define (my-filter predicate sequence)
  (accumulate (lambda (element rest)
                (if (predicate element)
                    (cons element rest)
                    rest))
              '()
              sequence))
```

For example:

```
(my-filter odd? (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
=> '(1 3 5 7)
```